# Backend doesn't work after installing Porto theme: Mage registry key "_singleton/all/update" already exists

Tags: backend, third-party-module

I get this error after installing Porto theme and accessing to backend doesn't work, this is the same case: http://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864/comments?page=31&filter=all#comment_9645128

REPORT LOG: https://www.dropbox.com/s/06wxoinsveys4t9/error.txt?dl=0

Comment: Post config.xml of the module, error should be there

Comment: Porto is a Theme

Comment: Yeah, but also a module ;) Check for config.xml and post it

Comment: Sorry I am not a developer :P should be this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvxyoiz99idcn1q/config.xml?dl=0

Comment: Post the  content in the question, so we can identify the problem

Comment: I've put both report log and config.xml

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted the module `config.xml` file I cannot show you the explicit solution. It shouldn't, but sadly, this is a relatively common issue

You'd check for observer events in the `config.xml` file and identify the problem. Read this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608376/mage-registry-key-singleton-already-exists-error

**update**

Change this...

```
    <events>                
        <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
            <observers>
                <porto>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>porto/observer</class>
                    <method>hookTo_controllerActionPostdispatchAdminhtmlSystemConfigSave</method>
                </porto>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
        <store_edit>
            <observers>
                <porto>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>porto/observer</class>
                    <method>hookTo_storeEdit</method>
                </porto>
            </observers>
        </store_edit>
    </events>
```

For this...

```
    <events>                
        <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
            <observers>
                <YOUR_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_1>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>porto/observer</class>
                    <method>hookTo_controllerActionPostdispatchAdminhtmlSystemConfigSave</method>
                </YOUR_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_1>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
        <store_edit>
            <observers>
                <YOUR_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_2>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>porto/observer</class>
                    <method>hookTo_storeEdit</method>
                </YOUR_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_2>
            </observers>
        </store_edit>
    </events>
```

Replacing `YOUR_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_1` & `YOUR_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_2` by the strings you want, considering they should be unique. Then clear cache. Problem should be fixed

As modern themes usually install several submodules, you'd check the whole `app/code/XXX/Porto` folder, and do the same in every config file

Comment: Hi Raul, yes config.xml is there: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvxyoiz99idcn1q/config.xml?dl=0

Comment: Ok, read the updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help... Now I am clearing the cache then let you know... Please add me on Skype I need developer every day: overvolt_it

Comment: The problem still persist after cleaning the cache... I've renamed the 2nd identifier in "porto2", looking into Theme foldes I can see 17 x config.xml, for example: app\code\local\Smartwave\Megamenu\etc   .... Do I have to edit these file as well?

Comment: Yes, you should do the same in theme submodules, if proceed (if event identifiers are not unique)

Comment: Raul can you add me in skype please? overvolt_it